# .NET FileSystemWatcher goes into infinite loop when moving file

Tags: c#, .net, infinite-loop, filesystemwatcher

I have a issue with the FileSystemWatcher. I'm using it in a windows service to monitor certain folders and when a file is copied, it proccesses that file using a SSIS package. Everything works fine, but every now and then, the FileWatcher picks up the same file and fires the Created event multiple times in a infinate loop. The code below works as follow:

Firstly, this method is called by the windows service and creates a watcher :

```
    private void CreateFileWatcherEvent(SSISPackageSetting packageSettings)
    {   
      // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
      FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

      watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

      watcher.Path = packageSettings.FileWatchPath;

      /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
        the renaming of files or directories. */

      watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
        | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.Size;

      //Watch for all files
      watcher.Filter = "*.*";

      watcher.Created += (s, e) => FileCreated(e, packageSettings);

      // Begin watching.
      watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```

Next up, The Watcher.Created event looks something like this:

```
    private void FileCreated(FileSystemEventArgs e, SSISPackageSetting packageSettings)
    {
        //Bunch of other code not important to the issue

        ProcessFile(packageSettings, e.FullPath, fileExtension);
    }
```

The ProcessFile method looks something like this:

```
    private void ProcessFile(SSISPackageSetting packageSetting,string Filename,string fileExtension)
    {
        //COMPLETE A BUNCH OF SSIS TASKS TO PROCESS THE FILE


        //NOW WE NEED TO CREATE THE OUTPUT FILE SO THAT SSIS CAN WRITE TO IT      
        string errorOutPutfileName = packageSetting.ImportFailurePath + @"\FailedRows" + System.DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + packageSetting.ErrorRowsFileExtension;
        File.Create(errorOutPutfileName).Close();

        MoveFileToSuccessPath(Filename, packageSetting);              
    }
```

Lastly, the MoveFile Method looks like this:

```
    private void MoveFileToSuccessPath(string filename, SSISPackageSetting ssisPackage)
    {
        try 
        {
            string newFilename = MakeFilenameUnique(filename);
            System.IO.File.Move(filename, ssisPackage.ArchivePath.EndsWith("\\") ? ssisPackage.ArchivePath + newFilename : ssisPackage.ArchivePath + "\\" + newFilename);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SaveToApplicationLog(string.Format
                ("Error ocurred while moving a file to the success path. Filename {0}. Archive Path {1}. Error {2}", filename, ssisPackage.ArchivePath,ex.ToString()), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }            
    }
```

So somewhere in there, we go into a infinite loop and the FileWatcher keeps on picking up the same file. Anyone have any idea? This happens randomly and intermittently.

Comment: You are watching for LastAccess. Maybe your handler accesses the file? That would trigger an endless loop of OnLastAccess->Access->OnLastAccess->Access->...

Comment: Good catch. What should I be handling then for ONLY new file created?

Comment: Strange thing though. Would a File.Move() change the OnLastAccess time?

Comment: @nvoigt Your comment should be authored as an answer

Comment: @nvoight, please add your comment as an answer. Tx

Answer (score 2):

When using the FileSystemWatcher I tend to use a dictionary to add the files to when the notification event fires. I then have a separate thread using a timer which picks files up from this collection when they are more than a few seconds old, somewhere around 5 seconds.

If my processing is also likely to change the last access time and I watch that too then I also implement a checksum which I keep in a dictionary along with the filename and last processed time for every file and use that to suppress it firing multiple times in a row. You don't have to use an expensive one to calculate, I have used md5 and even crc32 - you are only trying to prevent multiple notifications.

**EDIT**

This example code is very situation specific and makes lots of assumptions you may need to change. It doesn't list all your code, just somethind like the bits you need to add:

```
// So, first thing to do is add a dictionary to store file info:

internal class FileWatchInfo
{
    public DateTime LatestTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsProcessing { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Checksum { get; set; }
}
SortedDictionary<string, FileWatchInfo> fileInfos = new SortedDictionary<string, FileWatchInfo>();
private readonly object SyncRoot = new object();

//  Now, when you set up the watcher, also set up a [`Timer`][1] to monitor that dictionary.

CreateFileWatcherEvent(new SSISPackageSetting{ FileWatchPath = "H:\\test"});
int processFilesInMilliseconds = 5000;
Timer timer = new Timer(ProcessFiles, null, processFilesInMilliseconds, processFilesInMilliseconds);

// In FileCreated, don't process the file but add it to a list

private void FileCreated(FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    var finf = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
    DateTime latest = finf.LastAccessTimeUtc > finf.LastWriteTimeUtc
        ? finf.LastAccessTimeUtc : finf.LastWriteTimeUtc;
    latest = latest > finf.CreationTimeUtc ? latest : finf.CreationTimeUtc;
    //  Beware of issues if other code sets the file times to crazy times in the past/future

    lock (SyncRoot) {
        //  You need to work out what to do if you actually need to add this file again (i.e. someone
        //  has edited it in the 5 seconds since it was created, and the time it took you to process it)
        if (!this.fileInfos.ContainsKey(e.FullPath)) {
            FileWatchInfo info = new FileWatchInfo {
                FullName = e.FullPath,
                LatestTime = latest,
                IsProcessing = false, Processed = false,
                Checksum = null
            };
            this.fileInfos.Add(e.FullPath, info);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, here is the process method as it now is

```
    private void ProcessFiles(object state) {
        FileWatchInfo toProcess = null;
        List<string> toRemove = new List<string>();
        lock (this.SyncRoot) {
            foreach (var info in this.fileInfos) {
                //  You may want to sort your list by latest to avoid files being left in the queue for a long time
                if (info.Value.Checksum == null) {
                    //  If this fires the watcher, it doesn't matter, but beware of big files,
                    //     which may mean you need to move this outside the lock
                    string md5Value;
                    using (var md5 = MD5.Create()) {
                        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(info.Value.FullName)) {
                            info.Value.Checksum =
                                BitConverter.ToString(md5.ComputeHash(stream)).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
                        }
                    }
                }
                //  Data store (myFileInfoStore) is code I haven't included - use a Dictionary which you remove files from
                //   after a few minutes, or a permanent database to store file checksums
                if ((info.Value.Processed && info.Value.ProcessedTime.AddSeconds(5) < DateTime.UtcNow) 
                   || myFileInfoStore.GetFileInfo(info.Value.FullName).Checksum == info.Value.Checksum) {
                    toRemove.Add(info.Key);
                }
                else if (!info.Value.Processed && !info.Value.IsProcessing 
                    && info.Value.LatestTime.AddSeconds(5) < DateTime.UtcNow) {
                    info.Value.IsProcessing = true;
                    toProcess = info.Value;
                    //  This processes one file at a time, you could equally add a bunch to a list for parallel processing
                    break;
                }
            }
            foreach (var filePath in toRemove) {
                this.fileInfos.Remove(filePath);
            }
        }
        if (toProcess != null)
        {
            ProcessFile(packageSettings, toProcess.FullName, new FileInfo(toProcess.FullName).Extension); 
        }
    }
```

Finally, `ProcessFile` needs to process your file, then once completed go inside a lock, mark the info in the `fileInfos` dictionary as `Processed`, set the `ProcessedTime`, and then exit the lock and move the file. You will also want to update the checksum if it changes after an acceptable amount of time has passed.

It is very hard to provide a complete sample as I know nothing about your situation, but this is the general pattern I use. You will need to consider file rates, how frequently they are updated etc. You can probably bring down the time intervals to sub second instead of 5 seconds and still be ok.

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for the comment. Please will you share with us all the code snippets? I think my question is answered above by nvoight, but would still be nice to see a proper way of doing this. I think the Checksum is a great idea.

Comment: @Fox. Indeed, we're saying the same. File accesses will change last access time, and therefore so will a checksum calc fwiw. If you can avoid monitoring last access time then do. I will post code shortly. (My original comment said file "moves" will change LastAccessTime - a bad typo: this is not usually true).

Comment: Ok, I've gone ahead and removed the entire NotifyFilter  and now everything works perfect! Thanks to everyone who assisted.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the hard work you've put in to explain this to me. I wish I could pick two answers, but +1 to you for the help.

Comment: By the way, I think you should make your code a bit more generic and put it as an article on codeplex. You'll help alot of people with this kind of pattern.